# CMake/Make cannot find libusb

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake, libusb

I'm new to C/C++ and am trying to build and run [ttwatch](https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch) from github locally on an Ubuntu machine (Trusty Tahr). Instructions include installing some libraries first: cmake, openssl, curl, libusb, and include a note to install the "-dev" versions (eg. libssl-dev, libcurl-dev, libusb-1.0-0-dev). I'm having some trouble with libusb. I see questions about this all over the internet, but haven't yet found a solution that works.

Running `cmake .` appears to work fine:

```
meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ cmake .
-- Enabled daemon function
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
--  - Libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/meowmeow/code/ttwatch
```

But running `make` shows that libusb is not being located properly:

```
meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ make
[ 42%] Built target libttbin
[ 42%] Built target libttwatch
[ 42%] Built target ttbincnv
[ 42%] Built target ttbinmod
[ 42%] Built target manifest
Linking CXX executable ttwatch
CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/ttwatch.c.o: In function `main':
/home/meowmeow/code/ttwatch/src/ttwatch.c:1618: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/meowmeow/code/ttwatch/src/ttwatch.c:1796: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
...
```

If I check `/usr/includes/`, I see libusb:

```
meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ ls /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h 
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
```

And dpkg shows:

```
meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/copyright
/usr/include
/usr/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz


meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0
/.
/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
```

The file `ttwatch/includes/libttwatch.h` includes libusb as `#include <libusb.h>`, and I've tried modifying that to `#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>`, in hopes of better matching my `/usr/includes/` files, but that didn't change the error output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Using `make VERBOSE=1`does show -lusb, and not -lusb-1.0:

```
...
/usr/bin/c++ -g CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/ttwatch.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/log.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/options.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/json.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/download.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/firmware.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/misc.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/get_activities.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/update_gps.c.o CMakeFiles/ttwatch.dir/src/set_time.c.o -o ttwatch -rdynamic libttwatch.a libttbin.a -lusb -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl
```

And `libusb.so` appears to exist:

```
meowmeow@kittytown:~/code/ttwatch$ dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so 
libusb-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so
```

I tried uninstalling libusb-dev (`sudo apt-get remove libusb-dev`) and installed libusb-1.0 (`sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0`) to see if that would solve the issue. I now have a `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so` (note the 1.0) instead, but am now getting this from `make`:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so', needed by ttwatch'. Stop.
```

Comment: Do `make VERBOSE=1` and check the actual call of the linker (check `-l`, `-L` flags, etc). The `CMakeLists.txt` might be adding `-lusb` linking dependency and not `-lusb-1.0`.

Comment: I've checked https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindLibUSB.cmake and checks for `usb-1.0`and `usb`. Did you install another `libusb` by hand? Check if the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so` exists.

Comment: run `dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so` to see which package installed the file.

Comment: I've added the code to the question and removed it from the comments. Thanks!

Comment: The no rule error comes because the .so file might be gone after the uninstall and cmake doesn't know about it yet. Execute `cmake .` to rebuild the cmake cache and the `Makefile`s. `make` should work after that.

Comment: I deleted `CMakeCache.txt`, `CMakeFiles/` and `MakeFile` and re-ran `cmake .` and that worked!! Thank you! If you want to put your solution in an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Great, it worked. A added an answer a few minutes ago explaining all that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not aware that Debian has the packages [`libusb-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libusb-dev) and
[`libusb-1.0-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libusb-1.0-0-dev). From the package information I cannot tell why there are 2
packages for the same library, perhaps `libusb-dev` is an older version with a
different API and other packages might still have that as a dependency. So
removing the package might not be a good idea, unless you don't care/need
packages depending on `libusb-dev`, in which case you can do `apt-get purge
libusb-dev && apt-get autoremove`. Be ware that this **might** uninstall
packages that you need. So do it only if you know what you are doing.

I did not expect that Debian allows you to install both packages at the same
time, but this could be if the APIs of both libraries are different and don't
conflict with each other.

This seems to confuse `cmake`, which somehow cannot handle when both libraries
are simultaneously installed. I've gone through the [issues](https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch/issues) page and I
haven't found an issue relating to that. So if you cannot manage to build it,
I'd suggest that you go to the [issue](https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch/issues) page, if you don't have an github
account, create one and leave a bug report about building the package when
[`libusb-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libusb-dev) and [`libusb-1.0-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libusb-1.0-0-dev) are simultaneously installed.

Another option would be to make a small modification in the file `cmake_modules/FindLibUSB.cmake` before you do

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
```

Find the line `find_library(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY`, on the [current stable version it is line 62](https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindLibUSB.cmake#L62). The next line is `NAMES`
and the next line is `usb-1.0 usb`. Remove the `usb` from that, so that
`find_library` only searches for `libusb-1.0`. Save the file and then you can do

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
```

This should fix the problem.